# google nearby places search results in "invalid request"

Tags: search

I am using Google's nearbysearch API.

Here is my url:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?key=&location=30.2981490,-97.7234120&type=atm&language=en&rankby=distance

I'm invoking it in Ruby with

> `curl #{url}`

No matter what i change, location, type, rankby to radius, I get:

> INVALID_REQUEST

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of query string. it worked

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?type=atm&rankby=distance&location=30.2981490,-97.7234120&language=en&key=api_key
```